# Does imply f and g are relatively prime in K[x], that f- yg is irreducible in K(y)[x]?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials, fraction-field

**Problem:** Suppose that $K$ is a field and that $f$ and $g$ are relatively prime in
$K[x]$. Show that $f- yg$ is irreducible in $K(y)[x]$.

**My attempt:** Consider the polynomial $f-gY\in (K[x])[Y]$. This polynomial is irreducible. Indeed, if it were not, since its degree is over $(K[x])[Y]$ is $1$, $f-yg=(a-by)c$ where $a, b, c\in K[x]$ and the degree of $c$ over $K[x]$ is at least $1$. Then $f-ac=(g-bc)Y$, therefore $f=ac$ and $g=bc$ which contradicts $f$ and $g$ relatively prime.

Now, because $f-gY$ irreducible, if $y$ transcendental over $K$, $f-gy$ will be transcendental over $V[x]$, where $V$ is the k-vectorial space generated by $\lbrace y^n; n\in \mathbb{Z} \rbrace \cup \lbrace 1\rbrace$.

Finally, by Gauss's lema $f-gy$ is irreducible over $K(y)[x]$, since $K(y)$ is the fraction field of $V$.

I don't know if my proof is correct or not... moreover, I don't know how I can prove the statament when $y$ is algebraic.

**Comments:** This exercise is 5.4 of the book *a course in Galois theory by Garling*.

Comment: This is obviously false if $y$ is algebraic. Take $f=x+1,g=x,y=1$.

Comment: @GreginGre but in this case $f-yg=1$ and $1$ is an irreducible element...

Comment: No, it isn't. An irreducible element is by definition non invertible. (or, if you prefer to stick to the context of your question: an irreducible polynomial of $K[X]$ is non constant).